# How to write to an already opened .xlsx file with golang

Tags: go, xlsx

The title is as follows.

If it is easy to implement with additional packages, it is better than that.
It is even better if it is lightweight.

Please teach an example if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [xlsx package](https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
)

func main() {
    var file *xlsx.File
    var sheet *xlsx.Sheet
    var row *xlsx.Row
    var cell *xlsx.Cell
    var err error

    file = xlsx.NewFile()
    sheet, err = file.AddSheet("Sheet1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
    }
    row = sheet.AddRow()
    cell = row.AddCell()
    cell.Value = "I am a cell!"
    err = file.Save("MyXLSXFile.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Mostafa Solati.
I saw the your source code shown.
In the source code it appears to be creating a new Excel file.

I am sorry for my poor English.
What I want to handle is not a new file.
The main point is whether can write to an already open .xlsx file.

For example, we are considering collaboration between VBA and golang.
① "macro.xlsx" → start golang.
② golang → Write to a specific cell of "macro.xlsx" already open.

I wanted to confirm that this kind of thing is possible.

* Since it deals with macros, it was exactly "xlsm".

Comment: @gaccha I'm affraid to say you can't do that , every process that opens a file should close it in order to avoid conflicts between writes.

Comment: It is a pity that I can not do that.
But I think that what you say is true as well.
I will try another method.
Thank you for taking the precious time.